# Magento 2.4 - Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/items.phtml

Tags: magento2.4.4

Hi I am getting the following error in my log

main.CRITICAL: Exception: Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/items.phtml on line 244 in /vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61

items.phtml line 244

`<!-- <input type="hidden" name="uenc" value="<?php echo $postParams['data']['uencs']; ?>"> -->`

Kindly help me understand the same. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `$postParams` variable is `null` rather than the expected array containing `data` as key. How is this variable defined? Presumably it's POST data? Maybe the page is loaded from a redirect and the POST data is lost?

Answer (score 0):

**In line no. 243 add this code**

```
<?php
     /** @var $viewModel PreparePostData */
     $viewModel = $block->getViewModel();
     $postArray = $viewModel->getPostData(
     $block->escapeUrl($block->getAddToCartUrl($_item)),['product' => $_item- 
     >getEntityId()]);
     $value = $postArray['data'][ActionInterface::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED];
?>
```

You can get **'uenc'** value in **$value** object

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding **?? ''** to the end of the echo command.It expects a value and if there's none there you get that null error. This fix will leave a blank string instead of null so the exception should go away.

```
<!-- <input type="hidden" name="uenc" value="<?php echo $postParams['data']['uencs'] ?? ''; ?>"> -->
```